# Thread.Sleep c#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want to put a thread to sleep, and I don't have a sleep method.

I have using `System.Threading`.

In my code i write :

```
Thread t = new Thread(StartPointMethod);
t.
```

In the Methods list there is no Sleep....

What could be the problem?

Comment: which vs version .. some times it any be a prob with intelllisence

Comment: i have vs2008 with sp1 @Sudantha

Comment: What you want.Do you want to sleep current thread?Or You want to sleep a thread from another thread.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? Putting a thread to sleep is often a really bad idea. There is probably a better way to do what you want.

Comment: @Eric Lippert I need to load 8 pictures by interval of 2 seconds...i can't think of any other idea....

Comment: @olia: If you want to do something on an interval, use a Timer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Comment: +1 @Jim:  If you want to do something every 2 seconds, use a Timer to trigger at 2 seconds.  Timers exist for precisely this reason.

Comment: Yep, those guys are right. Do not put a thread to sleep if you want something to happen two seconds later. Either use a timer, or, in the next version of C#/VB with the new "async" feature you can call a method that means "asynchronously wait for two seconds; do other short-duration work on this thread while you're waiting and then pick up here where we left off". That way you don't waste a perfectly good thread. Threads are expensive, and you made them to do work; don't put them to sleep when they could be doing something.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This code for sleep current thread for 20 second.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
```

Comment: `t.Join(20000)` doesn't cause the other thread to sleep. It just waits up to 20 seconds for the other thread to terminate. If the thread doesn't terminate within that period, `Join` returns, but the other thread is unaffected.

Answer (score 12):

Use this method in any method in your new thread that you want to sleep.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
```

Answer (score 10):

Sleep is a static method on 'Thread', not an instance method. So the way to make you Thread sleep is to have a Thread.Sleep statement inside it executing method.

Since Thread.Sleep will always make the executing thread sleep, you can do something in the line of the example below.

```
    private void Foo()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadWorker));
        t.Start();

        t.Join();
    }

    private void ThreadWorker()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Prior to sleep");
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Console.WriteLine("After sleep sleep");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation of Thread.Sleep applying to the current thread you are in.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way for thread A to tell thread B to sleep. That is, you can't write:

```
Thread t = new Thread(...);
t.Start();
t.Sleep();
```

You *can* [suspend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend.aspx) a thread, and then resume it later, but this is a very bad idea. Doing so risks all kinds of potentially disastrous consequences. There's a reason that `Thread.Suspend` has been obsoleted.

In normal code (i.e. outside writing debuggers and OS-level stuff), there's never a good reason to suspend a thread. And there's *almost* never a good reason to call `Thread.Sleep`. If you find that you need to suspend or sleep a thread, there's almost certainly a design problem that you need to address.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use this code  :

```
Thread.Sleep(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand a little on the (correct) answers above, Thread.sleep is a **static** method. Static methods are associated with a class (Thread), but not a particular *instance* of the class.

So, to call Thread.Sleep - you just write (as has been said above) "Thread.Sleep(msecs)" - you don't need to create a thread to call the method.

Answer (score -1):

Thread.Sleep(milliseconds) lets the current thread sleep for x number of milliseconds. There is no way for a thread to put another thread to sleep. Thread.Sleep always refers to current thread.

Comment: Your answer is not adding anything that was not already suggested by the numerous older answers.

Answer (score -2):

The System.Thread has a function specifically made for that.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
```

The Sleep function takes one argument in milliseconds.